# How to solve an production.ERROR: Cannot use string offset as an array while trying to pass data to an array

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass data to an array that stores data when i add a product to my cart.

When i ever try to do this, i get an error

`production.ERROR: Cannot use string offset as an array`

i was expecting the product details to be passed to my cart. but then i encountered the above error.

This is what I am trying

```
  public function addBooktoCart($id)
    {
        $book = Transactions::findOrFail($id);

        $cart = session()->get('cart', []);

        if(isset($cart[$id])) {

            $cart[$id]['quantity']++;

        } else {

            $cart[$id] = [. // This is were the error is pointed too //
                "name" => $book->title,

                "quantity" => 1,
                "price" => $book->price,

                "image" => $book->file
            ];
        }

        session()->put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Book has been added to cart!');

    }
```

Please help

Comment: Is the period before the comment a typo or is it actually in the code?

Comment: yea its a typo, i was trying to make a comment there @aynber

Comment: Try `Log::info($cart);` and check your logs in `storage/logs` to see what `$cart` contains.

Comment: alright @aynber

Comment: i received a log not found, then i made a var dump on $cart and i got this "string(1) "1" "

Comment: So `session()->get('cart', []);` is a `1`. You'll have to track down where it's being set to 1 and why.

Comment: funny thing is i am follwing a very recent tutorial which I have filled line for line  @aynber https://www.positronx.io/laravel-livewire-add-product-to-shopping-cart-tutorial/

Comment: maybe your previous code is wrong, just clear the session and check again